# flutter and firebase_messaging - how fix extremal slowly build?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I added firebase_messaging package in my flutter app. After it build app is extremal slowly - 12-14 minutes. Although in XCode it is much faster(about 1-2 minutes). I found this [solution](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2751). I try f
irestore-ios-sdk-frameworks, but I have many warnings when build app and result error:

```
  `"std::__1::thread::hardware_concurrency()", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::local::LevelDbRemoteDocumentCache::LevelDbRemoteDocumentCache(firebase::firestore::local::LevelDbPersistence*, firebase::firestore::local::LocalSerializer*) in
      FirebaseFirestore(leveldb_remote_document_cache.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      -[FIRCollectionReference initWithPath:firestore:] in FirebaseFirestore(FIRCollectionReference.o)
      -[FIRCollectionReference initWithQuery:] in FirebaseFirestore(FIRCollectionReference.o)
      -[FIRCollectionReference isEqual:] in FirebaseFirestore(FIRCollectionReference.o)
      -[FIRCollectionReference isEqualToReference:] in FirebaseFirestore(FIRCollectionReference.o)
      absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view::string_view<std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in FirebaseFirestore(FIRCollectionReference.o)
      -[FIRCollectionReference parent] in FirebaseFirestore(FIRCollectionReference.o)
      -[FIRCollectionReference path] in FirebaseFirestore(FIRCollectionReference.o)
      ...
  "___cxa_free_exception", referenced from:
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in FirebaseFirestore(FIRDocumentSnapshot.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in FirebaseFirestore(FIRFieldPath.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in FirebaseFirestore(FIRQuery.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in FirebaseFirestore(FSTUserDataConverter.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in FirebaseFirestore(write_batch.o)
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in FirebaseFirestore(query_snapshot.o)
      std::__1::__throw_future_error(std::__1::future_errc) in FirebaseFirestore(document_reference.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
Encountered error while building for device.`
```

I use this package:

```
 `firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3`
```

This is my changes for pod file:

`pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '7.3.0'`

Perhaps the reason is the version mismatch? Any advice?